# Send Push Notification to multiple tokens with PHP (iOS)

Tags: php, ios, apple-push-notifications

I've a database with all the devicetokens. I proceed to pick up the tokens from the database, but my script doens't work then anymore (the pushes don't send).

This is my script:

```
<?PHP

$db_user = "xxx"; // Gebruiker voor MySQL
$db_pass = "xxx"; // Wachtwoord voor MySQL
$db_host = "localhost"; // Host voor MySQL; standaard localhost
$db_db = "xxx"; // Database

// Als je al ergens anders een database connectie hebt gemaakt,
// maak dan van de volgende twee regels commentaar (# of // ervoor zetten)
mysql_connect($db_host,$db_user,$db_pass);
mysql_select_db($db_db);

$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM iospush");

                                while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
                                    $deviceToken = $row["devicetoken"];
                                    }

if($_POST['message']){

//  $deviceToken = 'xxx';

    $message = stripslashes($_POST['message']);

    $payload = '{
                    "aps" : 

                        { "alert" : "'.$message.'",
"badge" : 1
                        } 
                }';


    $ssl='xx.pem';

    $ctx = stream_context_create();
    stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'local_cert', $ssl);
    stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'passphrase', 'xxx');
    $fp = stream_socket_client('ssl://gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195', $err, $errstr, 60, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT, $ctx);
    if(!$fp){
        print "Failed to connect $err $errstrn";
        return;
    } else {
        print "Notifications sent!";
    }

    $devArray = array();
    $devArray[] = $deviceToken;

    foreach($devArray as $deviceToken){
        $msg = chr(0) . pack("n",32) . pack('H*', str_replace(' ', '', $deviceToken)) . pack        ("n",strlen($payload)) . $payload;
        print "sending message :" . $payload . "n";

        fwrite($fp, $msg);
    }
    fclose($fp);
}

?>
<form action="pushios.php" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="message" maxlength="100">
    <input type="submit" value="Send Notification">
</form>
```

Please help me to make this working!

Thanks in regard!

Comment: More information needed.  What exactly do you mean by "It doesn't work anymore"?  Does it show an error message?  Where does it fail in the script?

Comment: The Push Notifications don't send anymore.

Comment: You overwrite $deviceToken all day - you never check against $deviceToken ... do you really know anything about PHP?

Comment: Rick, json_endode/decode will make your life easier.

Comment: @djot YES! I DO! Check the while statement...

Comment: No, you don't. You SELECT * [so everything], and then put all "rows" into $deviceToken - BUT, only the last row is kept in $deviceToken. AND, you do not use $deviceToken anywhere else - so you do not check against it.

Comment: @djot Ok, thats the reason why I here. I can't make it work so i ask for help? Thats the goal of Stack?

Comment: Well, and it's legitimate to ask if you yourself have any plan or just let others do the work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
$deviceToken = ARRAY();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
  $deviceToken[] = $row["devicetoken"];
}
```

...

```
// or use ($devArray = $deviceToken;)

foreach($deviceToken as $token){
    $msg = chr(0) . pack("n",32) . pack('H*', str_replace(' ', '', $token)) . pack        ("n",strlen($payload)) . $payload;
```

Comment: sends only to one token, not to others.. can you post full answer? ( I am new to PHP, so I am misplacing the code..)

Comment: update: I moved `fwrite($fp, $msg);` in `foreach`. now it sends to 2 users that I was sending to, but last time when I tried `fwrite` in `foreach` it didn't go to all the users when I tried sending it to 100 users

Answer (score 0):

```
function addStoryData() {

    header("Content-Type:application/json");

    $notification = $this->input->post('message');

    $device_id = $this->db->select('device_id')
                               ->from('tbl_device')
                               ->where('device_type','iPhone')
                               ->get()
                               ->result_array();

    //$this->sendApplePushNotification($device_id,$notification,1);

    foreach ($device_id as $d_id) {                           

        $device_id  = $d_id['device_id'];
        $this->sendApplePushNotification($device_id,$notification,1);
    }


}

function sendApplePushNotification($tToken,$tAlert,$notification)
{

     /*
        print_r($tToken);
        echo '----------------------------';
        print_r($tAlert);
        echo '----------------------------';
        print_r($detail);
        echo '----------------------------';
        print_r($notification);
        echo '----------------------------';
        print_r($tToken);
        die;
    */    
        $tPayload="test";
        //$tHost = 'gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com';
        $tHost = 'gateway.push.apple.com';

        $tPort = 2195;

        // Provide the Certificate and Key Data.
        // home/ibliocrq/public_html/shopostreet.com/shopostreet/application/ckShopostreet_development.pem
         //echo $this->config->item('pushcertDevelopment.pem');die;

        //echo base_url('RestAPI/pushcertDevelopment.pem');
        //die;
        $tCert =  '/home/chatstor/public_html/readify/pushcertDistribution.pem';
         //$tCert =  '/home/chatstor/public_html/readify/pushcertDevelopment.pem';


        //$tCert = 'ckUnionMallProdution.pem';

        // Provide the Private Key Passphrase (alternatively you can keep this secrete

        // and enter the key manually on the terminal -> remove relevant line from code).

        // Replace XXXXX with your Passphrase

        $tPassphrase = 'ibl@2017';

        // Provide the Device Identifier (Ensure that the Identifier does not have spaces in it).

        // Replace this token with the token of the iOS device that is to receive the notification.

        //====================
        // $tToken = 'da38439e7b2bf83bfae2011eb680debdfeeded66602f685033fd4b25101d31a2';

        //====================

        // The message that is to appear on the dialog.

        //====================
        // $tAlert = 'Test Heartfelt Push Notification';
        //====================

        // The Badge Number for the Application Icon (integer >=0).

       // $tBadge = 1;
        $tBadge = intval($notification);

        // Audible Notification Option.

        $tSound = 'default';

        // The content that is returned by the LiveCode "pushNotificationReceived" message.

        //====================
       // $tPayload = 'You get a New Bubble';
        //====================

        // Create the message content that is to be sent to the device.

        $tBody['aps'] = array (
        'alert' => $tAlert,
        'badge' => $tBadge,
        'sound' => $tSound,

        //'detail' => $detail, 
        ); 

        //print_r($tBody);

        $tBody ['payload'] = $tPayload;
        //$tBody ['bubble_id'] = "101";

        // Encode the body to JSON.

        $tBody = json_encode ($tBody);

        // Create the Socket Stream.

        $tContext = stream_context_create ();

        stream_context_set_option ($tContext, 'ssl', 'local_cert', $tCert);

        // Remove this line if you would like to enter the Private Key Passphrase manually.

        stream_context_set_option ($tContext, 'ssl', 'passphrase', $tPassphrase);

        // Open the Connection to the APNS Server.

        $tSocket = stream_socket_client ('ssl://'.$tHost.':'.$tPort, $error, $errstr, 60, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT|STREAM_CLIENT_PERSISTENT, $tContext);


        // Check if we were able to open a socket.

        if (!$tSocket)
        {
                echo json_encode(array("ResponseCode"=>"2","Result"=>"false","ResponseMsg"=> "APNS Connection Failed."));
                exit ("APNS Connection Failed: $error $errstr" . PHP_EOL);
        }

        // Build the Binary Notification.


        /*foreach($tToken as $deviceToken){

            echo $tToken['device_id'];

            $tMsg = chr (0) . chr (0) . chr (32) . pack ('H*', $tToken['device_id']) . pack ('n', strlen ($tBody)) . $tBody;

            // Send the Notification to the Server.

            $tResult = fwrite ($tSocket, $tMsg, strlen ($tMsg));



            if ($tResult){
                    echo json_encode(array("ResponseCode"=>"1","Result"=>"true","ResponseMsg"=> "Notification has been sent."));
            }else{
                    echo json_encode(array("ResponseCode"=>"2","Result"=>"false","ResponseMsg"=> "Notification could not sent."));
            }
        }
        fclose ($tSocket);*/
        //fclose($fp);


        $tMsg = chr (0) . chr (0) . chr (32) . pack ('H*', $tToken) . pack ('n', strlen ($tBody)) . $tBody;

        // Send the Notification to the Server.

        $tResult = fwrite ($tSocket, $tMsg, strlen ($tMsg));



        if ($tResult){
                echo json_encode(array("ResponseCode"=>"1","Result"=>"true","ResponseMsg"=> "Notification has been sent."));
        }else{
                echo json_encode(array("ResponseCode"=>"2","Result"=>"false","ResponseMsg"=> "Notification could not sent."));
        }

        // Close the Connection to the Server.

        fclose ($tSocket); 
}
}
```